# How to insert excel selected strings in arraylist

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

People please help me i have excel 2010 addin there is one button. i want to copy selected string into array list .

Comment: You need to give more details; post some code.

Comment: CaBieberach thank you for replay . I dont have code There is simply new project(excel add-in) in my solution. When i run solution i n excel makeing new add in where is my button i want to copy selected strings into arraylist which is in project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where u want to use arraylist, in a excel macro or in a c# program?